# Application runs, but eventually ends up with SIGSEGV or NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linux, mono, posix, mono-posix

I have the following program (full source):

```
using Mono.Unix;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

namespace StoneOS.ResourceMonitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var runner = new Timer(state =>
            {
                var cpu = CPUUsage();
                var ram = RAMUsage();
                var hdd = DriveUsage("/dev/sda3");

                Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] C: {1:N2} | R: {2:N2} | S: {3:N2} | H: {4:N2}", DateTime.Now, cpu, ram.Total, ram.Swap, hdd);
            }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static string LastReadCPULine = null;

        struct Jiffy
        {
            public double Total;

            public double Work;
        }

        public static double? CPUUsage()
        {
            // File path and descriptor, that holds the actual CPU data.
            var statsFile = "/proc/stat";
            // var unixInfo = new FileInfo(statsFile);
            var unixInfo = new UnixFileInfo(statsFile);

            // Read last queried data into cache.
            string last = LastReadCPULine;

            // Prepare for new read.
            List<string> output = new List<string>();

            // Read data.
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(unixInfo.OpenRead()))
            {
                string currentLine;

                while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    output.Add(currentLine);
                }
            }

            unixInfo = null; // clear...

            // Select the first entry, that should be total of CPU.
            string current = LastReadCPULine = output.First();

            // If there was no last entry, that means we cannot calculate - return zero.
            if (last == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return CalculateCPUUsage(last, current);
        }

        private static double CalculateCPUUsage(string last, string current)
        {
            Jiffy lastJiffy = GetJiffies(last);
            Jiffy currentJiffy = GetJiffies(current);

            double work = currentJiffy.Work - lastJiffy.Work;
            double total = currentJiffy.Total - lastJiffy.Total;

            return (work / total) * 100;
        }

        private static Jiffy GetJiffies(string statLine)
        {
            // Split on spaces.
            string[] parts = subsequentSpacePattern.Split(statLine);

            // Remove first entry (label - cpu).
            IEnumerable<double> convertedData = parts.Skip(1).Select(entry => Convert.ToDouble(entry));

            // Calculate the values for the Jiffy.
            return new Jiffy
            {
                Total = convertedData.Sum(),
                Work = convertedData.Take(3).Sum()
            };
        }

        struct Memory
        {
            public double Total;
            public double Swap;
        }

        private static Memory RAMUsage()
        {
            var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/free", "-b")
            {
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            List<string> output = new List<string>();

            using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
            {
                process.WaitForExit();

                string currentLine;

                using (var reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        output.Add(currentLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new Memory
            {
                Total = CalculateTotalMemoryUsage(output.Skip(1).Take(1).Single()),
                Swap = CalculateSwapUsage(output.Skip(2).Take(1).Single())
            };
        }

        private static Regex subsequentSpacePattern = new Regex(@"\s+");

        private static double CalculateTotalMemoryUsage(string memoryLine)
        {
            string[] parts = subsequentSpacePattern.Split(memoryLine);

            // Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] Memory: {1}", DateTime.Now, memoryLine);
            // Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] Memory: {1}", DateTime.Now, String.Join(", ", parts));

            string totalByteString = parts.Skip(1).Take(1).Single();
            string availableByteString = parts.Last();

            // Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] Total: '{1}'; Available: '{2}'", DateTime.Now, totalByteString, availableByteString);

            double total = Convert.ToDouble(totalByteString);
            double available = Convert.ToDouble(availableByteString);

            var percentage = (available / total) * 100d;

            // Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] Memory %: {1} (Total: {2}, Free: {3})", DateTime.Now, percentage, total, available);

            return 100d - percentage;
        }

        private static double CalculateSwapUsage(string swapLine)
        {
            string[] parts = subsequentSpacePattern.Split(swapLine);

            // Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] Swap: {1}", DateTime.Now, swapLine);
            // Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] Swap: {1}", DateTime.Now, String.Join(", ", parts));

            string totalByteString = parts.Skip(1).Take(1).Single();
            string freeByteString = parts.Last();

            // Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] Total: '{1}'; Free: '{2}'", DateTime.Now, totalByteString, freeByteString);

            double total = Convert.ToDouble(totalByteString);
            double free = Convert.ToDouble(freeByteString);

            var percentage = (free / total) * 100d;

            // Console.WriteLine("[{0:O}] Swap %: {1} (Total: {2}, Free: {3})", DateTime.Now, percentage, total, free);

            // We are interested in remainder.
            return 100d - percentage;
        }

        private static Regex multiSpacePattern = new Regex(@"\s+");

        private static double DriveUsage(string drive)
        {
            var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/df", String.Format("-B1 {0}", drive))
            {
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            List<string> output = new List<string>();

            using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
            {
                process.WaitForExit();

                string currentLine;

                using (var reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        output.Add(currentLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Second output line is the one we're looking for.
            var second = output.Last();

            string[] parts = multiSpacePattern.Split(second);

            if (parts.Length != 6)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Invalid column count in df's output: {0}", second));
            }

            var percentage = parts[4].TrimEnd('%');

            // Console.WriteLine("Output: {0}", second);
            // Console.WriteLine("[4] = {0}, percentage = {1}", parts[4], percentage);

            return Convert.ToDouble(percentage);
        }
    }
}
```

Just a basic resource monitor, that reads/requests some information from the system and reports every N seconds. This is used to reflect the errors happening in the actual application. This happens to error out in the same manner as actual app. The periodic interval is set as high to get to the errors faster for debugging purposes.

As can be seen around lines `41` & `42`, respectively:

```
// var unixInfo = new FileInfo(statsFile);
var unixInfo = new UnixFileInfo(statsFile);
```

I have set up two solutions. One utilizing the native `.NET/Mono` itself, the other - `Mono.Posix`.

When run by utilizing the native solution (`FileInfo`) - there are no problems, everything works as expected.

Now, when running with the `Mono.Posix` equivalent (`UnixFileInfo`), the software eventually ends up in a `System.NullReferenceException` or even worse - `SIGSEGV`.

`System.NullReferenceException` case:

> ```
> Unhandled Exception:
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   at System.String.IndexOfAnyUnchecked (System.Char[] anyOf, Int32 startIndex, Int32 count) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.String.IndexOfAny (System.Char[] anyOf) [0x00019] in /build/mono/src/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs:896
>   at Mono.Unix.UnixPath.CheckPath (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0
>   at Mono.Unix.UnixFileSystemInfo..ctor (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0
>   at Mono.Unix.UnixFileInfo..ctor (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0
>   at StoneOS.ResourceMonitor.Program.CPUUsage () [0x00008] in /home/stone/sandbox/StoneOS.ResourceMonitor/StoneOS.ResourceMonitor/Program.cs:44
>   at StoneOS.ResourceMonitor.Program.m__0 (System.Object state) [0x00001] in /home/stone/sandbox/StoneOS.ResourceMonitor/StoneOS.ResourceMonitor/Program.cs:20
>   at System.Threading.Timer+Scheduler.TimerCB (System.Object o) [0x00007] in /build/mono/src/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Timer.cs:317
> ```

`SIGSEGV` case:

> ```
> Stacktrace:
>
>
> Native stacktrace:
>
>         /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0xd546a) [0x7f2d9851f46a]
>         /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x133aeb) [0x7f2d9857daeb]
>         /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x3fde6) [0x7f2d98489de6]
>         /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x10200) [0x7f2d9823e200]
>         /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x204d70) [0x7f2d9864ed70]
>         /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x20bd4f) [0x7f2d98655d4f]
>         /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x20c159) [0x7f2d98656159]
>         /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x229cb3) [0x7f2d98673cb3]
>         /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x229d7f) [0x7f2d98673d7f]
>         [0x4150ff33]
>
> Debug info from gdb:
>
> warning: File "/usr/bin/mono-sgen-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
> To enable execution of this file add
>         add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/bin/mono-sgen-gdb.py
> line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
> To completely disable this security protection add
>         set auto-load safe-path /
> line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
> For more information about this security protection see the
> "Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
>         info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
> warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
> Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
> [New LWP 441]
> [New LWP 440]
> [New LWP 439]
> [New LWP 438]
> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
> Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
> 0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
>   Id   Target Id         Frame
>   5    Thread 0x7f2d95c9b700 (LWP 438) "Finalizer" 0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
>   4    Thread 0x7f2d956ff700 (LWP 439) "Timer-Scheduler" 0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
>   3    Thread 0x7f2d954fe700 (LWP 440) "Threadpool moni" 0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
>   2    Thread 0x7f2d954bd700 (LWP 441) "Threadpool work" 0x00007f2d9823ddeb in waitpid () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
> * 1    Thread 0x7f2d98c48780 (LWP 437) "mono" 0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
>
> Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f2d95c9b700 (LWP 438)):
> #0  0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
> #1  0x00007f2d9864cd46 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #2  
> #3  0x00007f2d9823c90e in sem_wait () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
> #4  0x00007f2d986ab5c6 in mono_sem_wait () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #5  0x00007f2d98624529 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #6  0x00007f2d986069e7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #7  0x00007f2d986b0dd5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #8  0x00007f2d98235314 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
> #9  0x00007f2d97f733ed in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
>
> Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f2d956ff700 (LWP 439)):
> #0  0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
> #1  0x00007f2d9864cd46 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #2  
> #3  0x00007f2d9823ac68 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
> #4  0x00007f2d986885ba in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #5  0x00007f2d9869c9c2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #6  0x00007f2d9860642f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #7  0x00007f2d986078dc in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #8  0x000000004152a6ad in ?? ()
> #9  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #10 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #11 0x0000000000000032 in ?? ()
> #12 0x00007f2d97002cd0 in ?? ()
> #13 0x0000000000000031 in ?? ()
> #14 0x00007f2d880025e0 in ?? ()
> #15 0x00007f2d956febb0 in ?? ()
> #16 0x00007f2d956fe9f0 in ?? ()
> #17 0x00007f2d956fe950 in ?? ()
> #18 0x000000004152a418 in ?? ()
> #19 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
>
> Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f2d954fe700 (LWP 440)):
> #0  0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
> #1  0x00007f2d9864cd46 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #2  
> #3  0x00007f2d97f802ca in clock_nanosleep () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
> #4  0x00007f2d9869df48 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #5  0x00007f2d98609abe in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #6  0x00007f2d986069e7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #7  0x00007f2d986b0dd5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #8  0x00007f2d98235314 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
> #9  0x00007f2d97f733ed in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
>
> Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f2d954bd700 (LWP 441)):
> #0  0x00007f2d9823ddeb in waitpid () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
> #1  0x00007f2d9851f500 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #2  0x00007f2d9857daeb in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #3  0x00007f2d98489de6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #4  
> #5  0x00007f2d9864ed70 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #6  0x00007f2d98655d4f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #7  0x00007f2d98656159 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #8  0x00007f2d98673cb3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #9  0x00007f2d98673d7f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #10 0x000000004150ff33 in ?? ()
> #11 0x00007f2d973fffa0 in ?? ()
> #12 0x00007f2d973ff108 in ?? ()
> #13 0x000000000000001d in ?? ()
> #14 0x00007f2d973ff108 in ?? ()
> #15 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #16 0x00007f2d800025e0 in ?? ()
> #17 0x000000000000001f in ?? ()
> #18 0x00007f2d954bc6d0 in ?? ()
> #19 0x00007f2d954bc5e0 in ?? ()
> #20 0x0000000041557efc in ?? ()
> #21 0x00007f2d97000d30 in ?? ()
> #22 0x00007f2d973fffa0 in ?? ()
> #23 0x00007f2d973f1ae8 in ?? ()
> #24 0x000000000000001f in ?? ()
> #25 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #26 0x000000000000001d in ?? ()
> #27 0x00007f2d954bd680 in ?? ()
> #28 0x00007f2d98673d3f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #29 0x000000004150ff33 in ?? ()
> #30 0x00007f2d97000d30 in ?? ()
> #31 0x00007f2d973f1ae8 in ?? ()
> #32 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #33 0x0000000000000025 in ?? ()
> #34 0x00007f2d973f1ae8 in ?? ()
> #35 0x00007f2d97000d30 in ?? ()
> #36 0x00007f2d973f1ae8 in ?? ()
> #37 0x00007f2d97000d30 in ?? ()
> #38 0x00007f2d954bc770 in ?? ()
> #39 0x00000000415577e4 in ?? ()
> #40 0x000000000000001f in ?? ()
> #41 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #42 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #43 0x000000000000001c in ?? ()
> #44 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #45 0x0000000000000025 in ?? ()
> #46 0x000000000000001f in ?? ()
> #47 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #48 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
> #49 0x00007f2d973f1ae8 in ?? ()
> #50 0x00007f2d973fffa0 in ?? ()
> #51 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
>
> Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f2d98c48780 (LWP 437)):
> #0  0x00007f2d97ebed57 in sigsuspend () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
> #1  0x00007f2d9864cd46 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #2  
> #3  0x00007f2d9823d3bb in read () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
> #4  0x00007f2d986897e1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #5  0x00007f2d985ac234 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #6  0x0000000041530c61 in ?? ()
> #7  0x00007f2d970168c0 in ?? ()
> #8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
>
> =================================================================
> Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
> a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
> used by your application.
> =================================================================
>
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

Most of the times, though, it's the `SIGSEGV` error.

What I have tried... well, besides switching back and forth from `FileInfo` and `UnixFileInfo` nothing, problem is, I don't know what to even *try*.

This is my first major `Mono` application targeted for Linux, hence have no idea what to do here.

I have walked through the [Mono GDB debugging guide](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/) - set up the *provided* `.gdbinit`, ran with `gdb` - result:

> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> [Switching to Thread 0x7ffff47fe700 (LWP 4558)]
> 0x00007ffff7a1cc47 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> (gdb) mono_backtrace 15
> #0  0x00007ffff7a1cc47 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #1  0x00007ffff7a1caf8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #2  0x00007ffff79f236d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #3  0x00007ffff79f7725 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #4  0x00007ffff79f8159 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #5  0x00007ffff7a15cb3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #6  0x00007ffff7a15ed4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #7  0x00007ffff79cdb16 in mono_array_new_specific ()
>    from /usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
> #8 0x400135cb in Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffe00f2410
> ```

This gives something what the default `mono --debug <path/to/exe>` doesn't - the `mono_array_new_specific()` call, though, I don't know of what relevance it is here.

I am unsure whether this is a bug in the `Mono.Posix` library or something else, but this is really bugging me. Yes, for this particular example case I can get away with `FileInfo`, but in the real app I am actually utilizing `UnixSymbolicLinkInfo` which is causing the same problem.

`mono -V`:

> ```
> Mono JIT compiler version 3.10.0 (tarball Mon Oct  6 20:46:04 UTC 2014)
> Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
>         TLS:           __thread
>         SIGSEGV:       altstack
>         Notifications: epoll
>         Architecture:  amd64
>         Disabled:      none
>         Misc:          softdebug
>         LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
>         GC:            sgen
> ```

What makes my application **eventually** end up erroring out with a `SIGSEGV` or `System.NullReferenceException`?

Answer (score 0):

A NullReferenceException should never happen inside the class libraries (System.String class), so this must be a bug. Please report it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/. Ideally you should include in the report what is exactly the string used, and the parameter used, when calling the method IndexOfAny(). For that you may need to check the sources of Mono.Posix to see what's done inside Mono.Unix.UnixPath.CheckPath().